# Trouble Executing Code for a Chatbot

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a chatbot. When I run this code, I get an error saying, "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("message").value')" on line 11. When the code is run, the user should be able to type in "hi" and have the computer respond to it. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with line 11? Here's the code:

```
<html>
<!--Create text box for player to type in-->
<input type="text" id=â€œmessageâ€>
<!--Create paragraph to show chatbot's messages-->
<p id="chatbotText"></p>
<!--Create button to send messages to chatbot-->
<button onclick="input()">Send</button>
<script>
//function to process user messages
var input = function() {
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    //create array with list of phrases to use in response to "Hello"
    var helloMessages = ["Hello.", "Hi.", "Hello!", "Hi!", "Hello. How are you doing?", "Hi. How are you?"];
    //function to pick random phrase
    function randomWord(arr) {
        return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    }
    if(message === "hi" || message === "hello" || message === "hi!" || message === "hello!" || message === "hi." || message === "hello." || message === "hey." || message === "hey" || message === "hey!") {
        document.getElementById('chatbotText').innerHTML = "<p>randomWord(helloMessages)</p>";
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some slight changes to your code and it works. I changed the button to have an ID and the event to be raised from JavaScript.

```js
//function to process user messages
var button = document.getElementById("btnSubmit")
button.onclick = function() {

var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  //create array with list of phrases to use in response to "Hello"
  var helloMessages = ["Hello.", "Hi.", "Hello!", "Hi!", "Hello. How are you doing?", "Hi. How are you?"];
  //function to pick random phrase
  function randomWord(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }
  if (message === "hi" || message === "hello" || message === "hi!" || message === "hello!" || message === "hi." || message === "hello." || message === "hey." || message === "hey" || message === "hey!") {
    document.getElementById('chatbotText').innerHTML = "<p>randomWord(helloMessages)</p>";
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Create text box for player to type in-->
<input type="text" id="message">
<!--Create paragraph to show chatbot's messages-->
<p id="chatbotText"></p>
<!--Create button to send messages to chatbot-->
<button id="btnSubmit">Send</button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying so hard to fix this, and it's finally resolved. Now I can move on to programming in the responses for different messages.